# Setting up OAuth2 on Node - easiest way to handle users in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, oauth-2.0

I have set up an OAuth2 authentication server running on NodeJS. I’ve based it on the example in OAuth2orize for Passport.

**Now i need to switch the hardcoded users with ones in a MongoDB.**

I’ve tried out different solutions, but haven’t really been able to get any to work satisfactory, so i was hoping someone here would have an easier way of implementing it. I would prefer to not use mongoose, but just use the MongoDB driver.

The current set up for users looks like this:

```
var users = [
    { id: '1', username: 'bob', password: 'secret', name: 'Bob Smith' },
    { id: '2', username: 'joe', password: 'password', name: 'Joe Davis' }
];

exports.find = function(id, done) {
  for (var i = 0, len = users.length; i < len; i++) {
    var user = users[i];
    if (user.id === id) {
      return done(null, user);
    }
  }
  return done(null, null);
};

exports.findByUsername = function(username, done) {
  for (var i = 0, len = users.length; i < len; i++) {
    var user = users[i];
    if (user.username === username) {
      return done(null, user);
    }
  }
  return done(null, null);
};
```

It would be great to come up with a way where findByUsername just connects to the db, verifies if the username exists there, and returns the user object from the users collection.

Any ideas on how to fix this with the least hazzle?

Let me know if you need more of my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [mongojs](https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs) is what you need?

```
exports.findByUsername = function(username, done) {
    db.users.findOne({username: user.username},function(err, user) {
       if(err) return done(err);
       return done(null, user);
    });
};
```

Comment: MongoJS works nicely, i am however encountering a problem with getting the result from the db. It runs async which means when the response comes, the code that needed it has already run.... not being a node expert here, do you have any suggestions on how to solve that?

Comment: You will not find a viable sync solution for node js.  It is async by nature.  You should design your code accordingly or you'll face performance and compatability problems.  Your mock a bow however supports async behaviour via the done callback.  Are you sure async is not supported on the other parts of your code?    I would advice you to read about nodes event loop and how it is diferent from multithreaded applications.